# How to start webserver for blend4web in blender 2.80?

Tags: blend4web

I started to play around with blender 2.80. I "installed" and activated blend4web CE but i cant find the button to start/stop it in blender 2.80. Where can i find it?

Comment: This is probably best asked at https://www.blend4web.com forum

Comment: Its a plugin for blender, so blender leads the way. Also you can find a lot of questions about it in here. I could also ask blender questions at blenderartists.com - but if so, this site would be useless..

Comment: I didn't say it was off topic, just pointing out where you are most likely to get satisfying answers, but suit yourself

Comment: I understand you. Sorry i dont wanted to be harsh to you. Of course i went to another forum, i just was angry because this exchange site is crap and should be closed.